# Cargar datos en un Datatable mediante Ajax en asp net mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo un problema al cargar los datos a un Datatable de jquery, el proyecto se esta elaborando en asp .net mvc, utilizando entity framework. El problema es que no carga los datos al Datable, creo que es porque el llamado con ajax esta mal. Adjunto el código a continuación:

Controlador:
   dependiendo lo que retorne me muestra la tabla o el archivo json en texto plano.

```
public ActionResult ListarTodosLosClientes()
    {
        LogicaDeNegocio.CoordinadorDeClientes elCordinador = new LogicaDeNegocio.CoordinadorDeClientes();
        List<Model.Clientes> ListaDeClientes = elCordinador.ListarTodosLosClientes();
        var result = ListaDeClientes.Select(x => new Model.Clientes
        {

            nombreDelCliente = x.nombreDelCliente,
            primerApellidoDelCliente = x.primerApellidoDelCliente,
            segundoApellidoDelCliente = x.segundoApellidoDelCliente,
            estado = x.estado
        });


       //return View(result);   //Muestra la tabla pero no carga los datos  (Invalid JSON response)
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //Muestra el archivo json en texto plano. No muestra la tabla
    }
```

HTML

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br />
<center><h2>Lista de clientes</h2></center>

<br>

<table id="miTabla" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>1° Apellido</th>
            <th>2° Apellido.</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
       
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>1° Apellido</th>
            <th>2° Apellido.</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

JavaScript.  Creo que no se estan cargando los datos en la parte de ajax.??

```js
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#miTabla').DataTable({
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Clientes/ListarTodosLosClientes",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "dataSrc": " ",
                        "contentType": "application/jsonp"

                    }
                });


            });


    </script>
```

Comment: Saludos Diego, ¿has visto la documentación de DataTable?

Comment: Si Fredy de ahí me estoy apoyando para tratar de resolverlo.

Comment: Revisa este material: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿qué error te genera?, ¿has visto lo que hay en el request haciendo uso de F12, apartado de network?

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolverlo y hacerles las modificaciones correspondientes, debía hacer un cambio en el html y en el script. Se los dejo a continuación.

HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="miTabla">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                Nombre
            </th>
            <th>
                1° Apellido
            </th>
            <th>
                2° Apellido
            </th>
            <th>
                Estado
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombreDelCliente)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.primerApellidoDelCliente)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.segundoApellidoDelCliente)
                </td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.estado == 1)
                    {
                        estado = "Activo";
                        @estado;
                    }
                    else if (item.estado == 2)
                    {
                        estado = "Inactivo";
                        @estado;
                    }
                    else if (item.estado == 3)
                    {
                        estado = "Retirado";
                        @estado;
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```js
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#miTabla').DataTable({
                    "language": {
                        "lengthMenu": "Visualización _MENU_ ",
                        "search": "Buscar",
                        "zeroRecords": "No se ha encontrado nada - Lo sentimos",
                        "info": "Mostrando _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                        "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                        "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sFirst": "PRIMERO",
                            "sLast": "ULTIMO",
                            "sNext": "SIGUIENTE",
                            "sPrevious": "ANTERIOR"
                        },
                    }

                });
                $('#miTabla tbody')
                    .on('mouseenter', 'td', function () {
                        var colIdx = table.cell(this);

                        $(table.cells().nodes()).removeClass('highlight');
                        $('#miTabla').DataTable().search('').draw();
                    });
            });
        </script>
   
    }
```